# How to automate deployment of Blazor Server app

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Is there a way to automate the deployment of a Blazor Server app? The app keeps a connection open to the server-side DLLs which forces us to login to the server and manually stop the site before copying the revised files.  We tried to use PowerShell to stop the site but it is still leaving the DLLs locked. Only a manual stop via IIS panel unlocks the files.

Comment: In ASP.NET Core 6, the DLL's are not locked, so you can update them

Comment: That appears to be an experimental feature that is not guaranteed to make it into the release version.

Answer (score 1):

You have to stop the AppPool, not the site. Here are the PowerShell scripts we use (these happen to be called from an Octopus deployment so they use a replacement variable (`$AppName`) for the AppPool name, but you should get the gist).

Pre-deployment:

```
# Load IIS module
Import-Module WebAdministration

# Stop the app pool if not already stopped
if ((Get-WebAppPoolState($AppName)).Value -ne "Stopped") {
    Write-Output "Stopping IIS app pool $AppName"
    Stop-WebAppPool $AppName
}
```

Post-deployment:

```
# Load IIS module
Import-Module WebAdministration

# Start the app pool
Start-WebAppPool $AppName
```

Answer (score 0):

if you place a app_offline.htm in web root, apppool stops and dll unlocked.

Comment: In theory, yes. In practice many people have reported sporadic success with the app_offline.htm approach. See [this GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3793) for examples. Personally, we've found it much more reliable to use a script to explicitly stop the AppPool just prior to deploying the files. It has worked 100% of the time for us.